# ViewWillAppear called after a delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have a `UINavigationController` implemented, with a Root View Controller that hides or shows things depending on the choice that users make further down the navigation stack. All the hiding/showing options are implemented in a `viewWillAppear` function in the root view controller file. Now, when the root view controller first appears, there is no problem. However, when I go deeper, change some stuff and then press the back button several times and get to my root view controller, the ViewWillAppear function is not called immediately, but after a delay.

What is the result? The View that I left behind previously is first loaded and then gradually some buttons start to disappear. However, I want these buttons to disappear before the view shows. For that, I need `viewWillAppear` to execute before the view actually appear, just like the first time the app leads.

I realise that some developers had the problem of `viewWillAppear` not being called at all; however, that is not a problem in this case:)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                      initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                      identityPoolId:@"###-####-###"];

AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression *queryExpression = [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression new];

if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    queryExpression.indexName = @"FBID-index";
    queryExpression.hashKeyAttribute = @"FBID";
    queryExpression.hashKeyValues = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].userID;

}
else{
    queryExpression.hashKeyAttribute = @"ID";
    queryExpression.hashKeyValues = credentialsProvider.identityId;
}

dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
[[dynamoDBObjectMapper query:[User class]
                  expression:queryExpression]
 continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {

     if (task.error) {
         NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
     }
     if (task.exception) {
         NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
     }
     if (task.result) {

         AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;

         //there should really only be one entry with the specified CognitoID
         User *user = [paginatedOutput.items objectAtIndex:0];

         if(user.Login==true||user.Login==1){
             if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                 login.hidden = YES;

             }
             else{
                 FBlogin.hidden = YES;
                 [login setTitle: @"Log Out" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
             }


         }
         else{

             FBlogin.hidden = YES;
         }

         dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
     }
     return nil;
 }];

while (dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) { [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]]; }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, your problem is that your view is displayed before `viewWillAppear:` is called

Comment: yes indeed, thanks for editing the question! When I press the back button to get back to the root view controller, the view is displayed before viewWillAppear:

Comment: It sounds a bit like you're calling view transitions from a tread other than the main thread. Look through any background tasks you might be using and be sure to make UI-affecting calls on the main thread.

Comment: seems some strange behaviour, never encountered that. can you post your `viewWillAppear:` method

Comment: I just added the ViewWillAppear Function as an edit to the post!